# Visual Studio 2012 Web Express: show javascript methods in navigation

Tags: javascript, web, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I've recently decided to move from using Komodo Edit to Visual Studio 2012 Web Express for my html/css/javascript project (no asp.net features, just a static webpage.)

Some of my script files have a good number of methods in them and I frequently use Komo Edit's ability to jump to a given method via a navigation bar frequently.  I'd like to be able to do the same with Visual Studio 2012 Web Express, but the navigation bar that lists all of the scripts only shows the file names and does not have a dropdown carrot that lists the global variables and methods.

I've look around for a while as for how to enable this (intellisense works otherwise, allowing me to jump from a method call to its definition, even between files.)  I'm probably missing something fairly obvious here, but I suspect I may also need to download an extension...

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you couldn't find out how to enable this is that *Visual Studio 2012 doesn't have a navigation bar for javascript editing*. This feature has been [added in Visual Studio 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2013/07/16/javascript-editor-improvements-in-visual-studio-2013-preview.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, even if it's a few months later :P  I downloaded 2013 Express and decided to check it out.  One thing I noticed that it still gets confused when you have javascript functions inside MVC4's Razor views.  Perhaps I missed something or that has yet to be implemented.